# I don't know how to put the image inside of the border

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

I need to do like this:
[image: I need to do like this:]

I have to images, first is border, second is image with food, and i should combine them, but I could do only this:
[image: I have to images, first is border, second is image with food, and i should combine them, but I could do only this:]

And I should not use photoshop or something like this, I should create something like stencil for this image.

My code at the moment:

```css
.mainImg {
     width: 581px;
     height: 366px;
            
            
     .mainImgBorder {
         position: absolute;
         z-index: 1;
     }

     .img2 {
         position: relative;
         top: 50%;
         left: 50%;
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         clip-path: url('../img/mainImgBorder.svg');
     }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainImg">
    <img src="img/mainImgBorder.svg" class="mainImgBorder" alt="">
    <img src="img/img2.png" class="img2" alt="">
</div>
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: You may need to use the inner border as a clipping path. For more help you need to edit your question and add the code for the svg border

Comment: The `clip-path` needs to point at a path, not a whole SVG.. Eg. try `mainImgBorder.svg#myInnerPath`  Where myInnerPath is the `id` of a path in your SVG.  Note also that you'll want it to be a single path, not a shape that's the outline of a wavy line (as this one appears to be).

Comment: I don't understand you, Paul

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#clipPath

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden` to your containing div, and add `width: 100%` to get everything to fit.

```css
.mainImg {
    width: 581px;
    height: 380px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mainImgBorder {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.img2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    clip-path: url('../img/mainImgBorder.svg');
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainImg">
    <svg version="1.1" class="mainImgBorder" baseProfile="full" width="600" height="393" viewBox="0 0 600 393" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <path id="Background"
            fill="#4b4c4f"
            d="M 0 0 V 393 H 600 V 0 Z
                M 27.00,69.00
                C 27.00,61.00 33.00,55.00 41.00,55.00
                    41.00,55.00 41.00,41.00 41.00,41.00
                    41.00,41.00 55.00,41.00 55.00,41.00
                    55.00,33.00 61.00,27.00 69.00,27.00
                    69.00,27.00 531.00,27.00 531.00,27.00
                    539.00,27.00 545.00,34.01 545.00,41.00
                    545.00,41.00 559.00,41.00 559.00,41.00
                    559.00,41.00 559.00,47.82 559.00,55.00
                    567.00,55.00 573.00,61.00 573.00,69.00
                    573.00,69.00 573.00,324.00 573.00,324.00
                    573.00,332.00 567.00,338.00 559.00,338.00
                    559.00,338.00 559.00,352.00 559.00,352.00
                    559.00,352.00 545.00,352.00 545.00,352.00
                    545.00,360.00 539.00,366.00 531.00,366.00
                    531.00,366.00 69.00,366.00 69.00,366.00
                    61.00,366.00 55.00,360.00 55.00,352.00
                    55.00,352.00 41.00,352.00 41.00,352.00
                    41.00,352.00 41.00,338.00 41.00,338.00
                    33.00,338.00 27.00,332.00 27.00,324.00
                    27.00,324.00 27.00,69.00 27.00,69.00 Z" />
    
        <path id="OuterBorder"
            fill="none" stroke="#faae5d" stroke-width="5"
            d="M 17.00,59.00
                C 17.00,51.00 23.69,45.00 31.00,45.00
                    31.00,45.00 31.00,31.00 31.00,31.00
                    31.00,31.00 45.00,31.00 45.00,31.00
                    45.00,23.00 52.00,17.00 59.00,17.00
                    59.00,17.00 541.00,17.00 541.00,17.00
                    549.00,17.00 555.00,23.00 555.00,31.00
                    555.00,31.00 569.00,31.00 569.00,31.00
                    569.00,31.00 569.00,45.00 569.00,45.00
                    577.00,45.00 583.00,51.00 583.00,59.00
                    583.00,59.00 583.00,334.00 583.00,334.00
                    583.00,342.00 577.00,348.00 569.00,348.00
                    569.00,348.00 569.00,362.00 569.00,362.00
                    569.00,362.00 555.00,362.00 555.00,362.00
                    555.00,370.00 549.00,376.00 541.00,376.00
                    541.00,376.00 59.00,376.00 59.00,376.00
                    51.00,376.00 45.00,370.00 45.00,362.00
                    45.00,362.00 31.00,362.00 31.00,362.00
                    31.00,362.00 31.00,348.00 31.00,348.00
                    23.81,348.00 17.00,334.00 17.00,334.00
                    17.00,341.38 17.00,59.00 17.00,59.00 Z
                M 51.00,17.00M 23.00,45.00" />
    
        <path id="InnerBorder"
            fill="none" stroke="#faae5d" stroke-width="3"
            d="M 27.00,69.00
                C 27.00,61.00 33.00,55.00 41.00,55.00
                    41.00,55.00 41.00,41.00 41.00,41.00
                    41.00,41.00 55.00,41.00 55.00,41.00
                    55.00,33.00 61.00,27.00 69.00,27.00
                    69.00,27.00 531.00,27.00 531.00,27.00
                    539.00,27.00 545.00,34.01 545.00,41.00
                    545.00,41.00 559.00,41.00 559.00,41.00
                    559.00,41.00 559.00,47.82 559.00,55.00
                    567.00,55.00 573.00,61.00 573.00,69.00
                    573.00,69.00 573.00,324.00 573.00,324.00
                    573.00,332.00 567.00,338.00 559.00,338.00
                    559.00,338.00 559.00,352.00 559.00,352.00
                    559.00,352.00 545.00,352.00 545.00,352.00
                    545.00,360.00 539.00,366.00 531.00,366.00
                    531.00,366.00 69.00,366.00 69.00,366.00
                    61.00,366.00 55.00,360.00 55.00,352.00
                    55.00,352.00 41.00,352.00 41.00,352.00
                    41.00,352.00 41.00,338.00 41.00,338.00
                    33.00,338.00 27.00,332.00 27.00,324.00
                    27.00,324.00 27.00,69.00 27.00,69.00 Z" />
    </svg>
    <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/609817240e5a87efbb3458e0/609817240e5a873d7d345963_Gastronomy_Page%402x.jpg" class="img2" alt="">
</div>
```